# having an issue compiling php on ubuntu using apt-src

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, build, apt

i have been trying to compile php with apt-src and after about 20 minutes in one of the php tests fails trying to connect to mysql and itacked the script making the error here is the error from setup-mysql.sh

```
150419 17:48:11 [Warning] Can't create test file /home/php-build/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/mysql_db/orangehrm-Inspiron-N5010.lower-test
150419 17:48:11 [Warning] Can't create test file /home/php-build/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/mysql_db/orangehrm-Inspiron-N5010.lower-test
ERROR: 1005  Can't create table 'db' (errno: 13)
150419 17:48:11 [ERROR] Aborting

150419 17:48:11 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete


Installation of system tables failed!  Examine the logs in
/home/php-build/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/mysql_db for more information.

You can try to start the mysqld daemon with:

    shell> /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant &

and use the command line tool /usr/bin/mysql
to connect to the mysql database and look at the grant tables:

    shell> /usr/bin/mysql -u root mysql
    mysql> show tables

Try 'mysqld --help' if you have problems with paths.  Using --log
gives you a log in /home/php-build/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/mysql_db that may be helpful.

Please consult the MySQL manual section
'Problems running mysql_install_db', and the manual section that
describes problems on your OS.  Another information source are the
MySQL email archives available at http://lists.mysql.com/.

Please check all of the above before submitting a bug report
at http://bugs.mysql.com/
```

im running the compilation according to [this](http://kb.odin.com/en/967)
im running everything as root
note im compiling just the php and if there is a way to disable tests in php that would be grate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the source directory, open the rules file `debian/rules`.

Find the line `RUN_TESTS = yes` and comment it out like `#RUN_TESTS = yes` .

Then, tests won't run during the build.